# What does this error mean in deta hosting and how to resolve it ?? (unsupported frameworks)

Tags: node.js, express, web, heroku, backend

```
Error: Unsupported framework
    at getFramework (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/serverless-http/lib/framework/get-framework.js:63:9)
    at module.exports (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/serverless-http/serverless-http.js:14:21)
    at Object.handleCustom (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/detalib/deta/internal/handlers.js:20:19)
    at handler (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/detalib/deta/lib/handler.js:13:46)
    at Object.handler (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/detalib/deta/internal/debug/debugger.js:170:30)
    at Runtime.module.exports.handler (/var/task/_entry.js:11:18)
    at Runtime.handleOnceNonStreaming (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:74:25)
```

I deployed my backend API on deta, but it's showing this error in build logs

My backend API is just a node.js and express.js app.
Both of which are supported by deta micros
I don't know why it's not working.
please answer how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it regarding this piece of de deta documentation:
[deta deploy documentation](https://docs.deta.sh/docs/micros/deploy)
"
Node.js#

Most Node.js micro frameworks are supported, like Express, Koa, etc.

For Deta to be able to run your code, you need to call your app instance app and it has to be in a file called index.js, which is the only required file for a Node Micro. You also need to export app. Of course you could add more files and folders.
"
Try to fulfill the requirements about the file names and places to put your code.